# noUiSlider Handles Displaying In Incorrect Places

Tags: nouislider, polymer-3.x

I am attempting to setup a noUiSlider (version 13.1.5) from within a Polymer 3 custom element. The slider displays and technically works but the right handle is displaying where the left handle should be and the left handle is displaying outside of the container set out for the slider.
I've taken code from a Polymer 1 element that works 100% correctly but the handles aren't working in the Polymer 3 element.

The html code is as follows and has not changed between the two Polymer versions (other than the code now being in the `template` function for Polymer 3):

```
<div style="height: 50%; width: 100%">
    <div id="scoreRangeSelector" style="display: flex; flex-direciton: column">
        <div id="scoreRangeSelectorText">
            <p>Range Selection</p>
        </div>
        <div id="scoreRangeSelectorSlider"></div>
        <div id="scoreRangeInterval">
            <p>Score Interval</p>
            <input id="scoreRangeIntervalInput" on-change="_scoreRangeIntervalChanged" type="number" value="5" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Polymer code that sets up the slider is as follows and has not changed between the two Polymer versions (other than the retrieval of the element into the variable `slider`):

```
var slider = this.$.scoreRangeSelectorSlider;
noUiSlider.create(slider,
{
    connect: true,
    range:
    {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    },
    start: [0, 100],
    step: 1,
    tooltips: [true, true]
});
slider.noUiSlider.on("end", this._sliderMoved);
```

In the Polymer 1 element, the slider displayed correctly with it's handles, as follows:
https://www.pastiebin.com/5cd95545273b1

In the Polymer3 element, the slider displays but the right handle is displaying where the left handle should be and the left handle is displaying outside of the container, displaying under another container:
https://www.pastiebin.com/5cd9563ac618f

The handle that can be seen in the image is the handle that should be on the right hand side of the slider. The element being shown as "div.noUi-origin" is the left handle that should be on the left hand side of the slider.

The noUiSlider code seems to be adding transformations onto the handles that are pushing them off where they should be but I am unsure of what I am supposed to do to fix this.

Comment: Could you provide a running example of the new version with the issue? Side note: there's a typo in your CSS: `flex-direciton` => `flex-direction`.

Comment: I was not able to solve this issue directly, but instead found a suitable Polymer element that I installed and used: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/IftachSadeh/paper-range-slider. More recently, there is also https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/paper-slider that can be used for similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

set "direction: ltr" to "scoreRangeSelectorSlider" parent